# How to create schema extension without custom verified domain

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

According to this article:
[Add custom data to groups using schema extensions (preview)](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/extensibility_schema_groups)

If I want to create a custom schema extension, I must have a verify domain name like domain.com. Must ends with '.com'? How about test.domain.com? how about domain.net? How about without custom domain, just with default onmicrosoft domain?

I got this error when I try to create a schema extension:

`{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "Your organization must own the namespace gaoulm021 as a part of one of the verified domains.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "c443d4be-6258-4648-a36b-985662cfe433",
            "date": "2017-03-09T07:07:39"
        }
    }
}`

Any helpe?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently you must have a verified domain name like "domain.com", and yes it must end with .com.  We will be relaxing this in the future.

We don't support using the initial domain (like contoso.onmicrosoft.com) for extension definition naming.  We're unlikely to support this.

We are working on another mechanism that will allow you to create an extension definition without needing a verified domain, but the name will look uglier - something like `ext_{generated_random_string}_{your_schema_name}`.  This will make it easier to get started if you don't have a vanity domain.  We hope to make this update very soon.

**UPDATE 3/22/2017**: We've now introduced a new mechanism that means you can register schema extension definitions without having a verified .com domain. In this case you would set the `id` to simply the name of your schema (which cannot include an underscore character).  On creation, `id` will be set to `ext{8-char-random-alphanumeric}_{your-supplied-name}`.  Please let us know if this is working for you.  Also docs are updated with this info:  https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/schemaextension_post_schemaextensions

**UPDATE 6/16/2017**: We now additionally support creating schema extension ids namespaced based on verified domains that have a TLD root of `.net`,`.gov`, `.edu` and `.org`.  We've not updated the docs to reflect this, but will do soon.

Hope this helps,

Comment: Thanks for your apply. Another question： schema extension property can be used for filter? like application extension property?

Comment: Per the limitations in the conceptual doc, we unfortunately don't support $filter on an schema extension values yet.  However, this will be available *very* soon, Adam.

Comment: The following scope is required to execute this API: Directory.AccessAsUser.All in the docs you mentioned. Looks like the schema extension creation only allow delegate permission? Can use app permission to create it like open extension?

Comment: Interested in why do you need an application permission for this?  Application permissions should only really be used for daemon/service account apps.  That said, at some point soon we'll have an application only permission that will allow this.  Additionally we're looking to add an experience to the app registration portal that will allow you to more easily manage schema extensions.  If you like the idea of this, please add this as a suggestion on uservoice: https://officespdev.uservoice.com/

Comment: Because in our company solution, there are custom properties for created groups and users, that is in background process with workflow. We only can use app token to do it.

Comment: Managing the schema definition can be separate from updating the extended resources.  I can totally understand users and groups being updated through an app-only daemon process.

Comment: you got to be kidding me. what if you have co.uk or .io? sometimes I think people from microsoft,...... i don't know..

Comment: Hi @DanKershaw-MSFT ! Unfortunately, If I create a schemaExtension without verified domain and attach to a resource eg. groups then I won't be able to query the values of the extension with $select operator. Could you verify that's the expected behaviour or it is a bug? Thanks!

Comment: This is a bug, and it's being fixed. I believe it's related to the targetObject type in the schema definition not being case insensitive throughout the system.  We're fixing this.

Comment: Dan Kershaw, I tried to create schema extension with name `ext1464kbpf_velintest`, but I still receive 400 massage:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "Your organization must own the namespace ext1464kbpf as a part of one of the verified domains.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "cabe4a1a-12c7-40f6-81b6-d4c3280e5931",
            "date": "2019-03-25T12:44:08"
        }
    }
}
```

Am I missing something? How I can verify the `ext1464kbpf_velintest` string so I can create my schema?

Comment: @DanKershaw-MSFT I am having the same issue as Velin - any resolution on this? Right now I just leave it as `MySchema` and let MS decide what it needs to be prefixed with.